# Android Fragment Documentation Meaning

Tags: android, android-fragments

I don't understand the documentation found at:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CoordinatingWithActivity

In specific, the following sentence:

"For example, when the activity has received its onCreate() callback, a fragment in the activity receives no more than the onActivityCreated() callback."

Is this a typo? What was the author trying to say?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying to say that when the activity is created but not started, the furthest into the lifecycle that an attached fragment can be is `onActivityCreated()`. It's a mildly complicated way of saying that `onAttach()`, `onCreate()`, `onCreateView()` and `onActivityCreated()` can be called on the fragment before the activity is started, but `onStart()` and others will never be called until after the activity is started.